# Group By Lists in ListView when button click

Tags: android, listview

So I populate a `ListView` from the local database using `Custom Adapter`. What I want to do now is when I click a button the lists in the listview will change its order like what shown in the image. Can someone help me. Here's my code.

This is the current `ListView` -->   [SEE IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/dosf2z3oh/)

This is what I want to do --> [SEE IMAGE](http://postimg.org/image/4nqbjvm19/)

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public CustomAdaper(Context context,ArrayList<SampleObj> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final SampleObj i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {

        final SampleObj ei = (SampleObj)i;

        if (v == null) {
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.log_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.buttonID = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.buttonID);


            v.setTag(holder);
        } 

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        }

            holder.date.setText(ei.date);
            holder.time.setText(ei.time);
            holder.buttonID.setText(ei.buttonID);

            }

    return v;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView date;
    public TextView time;
    public TextView buttonID;
}

}
```

Comment: Try `ExpandableListView` and group item by status.

Comment: getting data from where? from DB or from where?

Comment: @Pragna getting data from the local database. I already get the data. My problem is how to arrange the list and group by.

Comment: you have to use expandable list

Comment: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use Expandale List 
[image]
[First see this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[then this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/)

[then this](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)

Comment: but how can I do that in my code? If I get all the data from the local database? :/

Comment: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Comment: in that child = new ArrayList<String>();
  child.add("Android");
  child.add("Window Mobile"); do like child.add=your cursor data

Comment: Thank you so much, I checked this as a correct answer. :)